# How do I specify hibernate join mappings?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, orm

Say I have the below two databases:

```
Employee
|Name|Age|Sex|

Table
|Employee_Name|Location|Brand|
```

I wish to execute following form of query:

```
select * from table,employee where table.employee_name=employee.name;
```

Now, I have specified the hibernate .hbm.xml files for both these tables. But in this case, the return value from the query is a join. Hence, how can I specify the data structure for it? Do I make a separate file, as in:

```
<id name="name" type="string" column="name">
  <generator class="native">
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="age"
          type="string"
          column="age" />
<property name="sex"
          type="string"
          column="sex" />
<property name="location"
          type="string"
          column="location" />
<property name="brand"
          type="string"
          column="brand" />
```

and then write the java-mappings file and make getters and setters for each one?

OR... do I simply add the columns to an existing java file without modifying any XML?

```
public class EmployeeModel // THIS IS THE JAVA MAPPING FILE FOR EMPLOYEE
{    private String name;
     private String age;
     private String sex;
     private String location;
     private String brand;

 // Getters and Setters for the above values.
```

Now, what happens when I want only Employee information in this case?
Please do help me out guys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like a really basic question to me. You should do some googling on one-to-many/many-to-one relationships and lazy initialization first because, this is a very broad subject.

Comment: I did... I can't use any embeddable or embed objects here. So I basically need to make newer data models for the return statement.

Comment: You dont have to use embeddable objects, you can add the relationship to yout XML:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: The below explanation only applies if you want to use native SQL for some reason.

Since you are not going to persist the returned values, you shouldn't create any mapping file (`.hbm.xml`). Hibernate can return a non-managed object. Just create an `EmployeeModel` class and use this:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select employee.Name, employee.Age, employee.Sex, table.Location, table.Brand from table, employee where table.employee_name=employee.name")
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmployeeModel.class));
```

as explained here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8394

If you want just the `Employee`, you can do this:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("select employee.* from from table, employee where table.employee_name=employee.name").addEntity(Employee.class);
```

This is explained here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8271

Comment: He never stated he wanted a non-managed object, he could just map the proper relationships and use HQL. Also, this solution is more like a last resource, not the first to start with.

Comment: But what about the returned value from the query? Where does that go?

Comment: Query q=session.createQuery(); List<SomeClass> list=q.list;
And i insist, do some googling about HQL, Relationships and lazy initialization.